# Regex in middle of text doesn't match

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I have a regex to find url's in text:

```
^(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?$
```

However it fails when it is surrounded by text:

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/0vZy6h/1

I can't seem to grasp why it's not working.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/bC1wPN/1

Comment: Seems to have issues with subdomains: https://regex101.com/r/bC1wPN/3

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons why the pattern does not work:

- `^` and `$` make it match the *entire string*
- `(?!:\/\/)` is a negative *lookahead* that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `://` substring. But `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+` means there can't be any `://`, so, you most probably wanted to fail the match if `://` is present to the *left* of the current location, i.e. you want a *negative lookbehind*, `(?<!:\/\/)`.
- `[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?` - matches 2 chars only if `$` is removed since the `{2,11}?` is a *lazy* quantifier and when such a pattern is at the end of the pattern it will always match the minimum char amount, here, 2.

Use

```
(?<!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bC1wPN/1). Add `\b` word boundaries if you need to match the substrings as whole words.

Note in Python regex there is no need to escape `/`, you may replace `(?<!:\/\/)` with `(?<!://)`.

Comment: Seems to have issues with getting the full subdomain: https://regex101.com/r/bC1wPN/2

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are not being matched.  Try adding space to the character sets checking for leading or trailing text.